# Synchronisation of managed instances

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, asynchronous, synchronization

I want to implement a sort of [multiton](http://bit.ly/SlkhNl) class (maybe also know as a [Manager Design Pattern](http://bit.ly/Slr1uy)) that loads (and manages) objects according to user configuration (the key of each object in the multiton is the primary key of the configuration record). These objects are disposed and recreated (i.e. reloaded) if changes in configuration is detected.

Other objects (external to the managed objects) interacts/communicates with these "managed" objects.

> E.g.
>   ManagerA manages instances of configured instances of ClassA. 
>   ObjectB retrieves an instance of ClassA via ManagerA and starts
>   interacting with the instance.

The problem is that the interaction between ObjectB and the managed instance of ClassA can potentially be on another thread than on which the ManagerA disposes the instance of ClassA and creates a new instance of ClassA (for the new changed configuration). I.e. the managed instance could be disposed just as (or just before) interaction with the managed object.

My question is how should one synchronise the instance management and interaction with these managed instances by external objects?

Comment: Simple solution: don't Dispose() them. Why is that needed anyway?

Comment: The managed instances actually use disposable instances them self so they need to be disposed or else system resources are leaked or locked until the GC collects the object.  E.g. the instances are configured to interact with serial port(s) as part of their functionality. I should not have to explain why that needs to be disposed...

Comment: From your linked page: The Manager controls all access to the Managee, so you situation shouldn't arise. And/or it's the wrong pattern.

Comment: @HenkHolterman this is exactly my question: how does one write a manager that controls all access to the "managee". Using the example of sending manual messages to/from the "managee" is not quite what I can do at the manager level. The reason is that manager simply manages instances of similar objects, but does not know the specific interactions (interfaces) of each object. The manager uses a factory  to load configured objects and only require that the object implements an IDisposable interface (only the consumer of the managed object knows the specific interface of the managed object).

Comment: @HenkHolterman If it is not the correct pattern then what is?

Comment: Seems like the Manager pattern is out (and implementing message-passing would have been a pain anyway). And MultiTon only solves a part of your problems.

Comment: " the managed instance could be disposed just as (or just before) interaction with the managed object." - this somehow seems to be the problem. I have a hard time imagining how/why this should happen.

Comment: @HenkHolterman basically the managed objects are "managed" (instantiated and disposed) on one thread and interacted with on another. Thus, without some sort of synchronisation between the "management" of the object and the "interaction" with the object, a race condition will exist. I'm currently investigating the use of the [Mediator pattern](http://bit.ly/Sn1DEM) to help with the synchronisation. But I'm still open to other suggestions...

Comment: But the managing thread should have some reason to Dispose an item. How can that happen when it's still being used? There should be some communication and control at that point.

Comment: @HenkHolterman As in my original post: These [managed] objects are disposed and recreated (i.e. reloaded) if changes in configuration is detected [by the manager]. This can happen at any time. To shed some light: we are writing a runtime configurable communications server. The "managed" object are configurable "protocols" to communicate with devices. Other objects then use these managed "protocol" objects to to queue actions with devices. But it is these "protocol" objects that get created/disposed while some other object is trying to queue an action.

Comment: Well, being able to reconfigure a protocol mid-journey is a heavy requirement. It will require a lot of locking and checking.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty difficult with no code, psuedo code, or such provided but...

If the client interacts with the managed protocol objects by enqueuing actions, and that queue of actions is longer-lived the the managed protocol object, perhaps it would be better to seperate that queue from the managed protocol and just pass a reference to the queue-like object to the client.

When something is enqueued, have your queue-like object check out a properly configured protocol object and use it.  I assume that while it is in use (meaning bytes are flying across the wire) it cannot be changed/configured.  After that one action has been completed, have the queue-like object then check the protocol object back in to your manager.  Upon checkin, if the manager has detected changes in the configuration it can dispose and recreate the protocol object, and if not then it is still sitting there ready to go for next use.  If upon detection of configuration change the object is not currently checked out, that recreation step can happen immediately.

The client is shielded from these details because it never access the protocol object directly.  (Though if that was a requirement then you could still apply a check-in and check-out concept to the protocol objects to make sure they are up to date, but it is harder to enforce since the client can forget to do the check in and re-checkout).

Comment: Your approach sounds allot like doing a [multi-reader-single-writer](http://bit.ly/OYZ0ts) lock on each managed object. It has crossed my mind many times, but it has its obvious problems (one is the same as you mentioned at the end of your post: clients can 'forget' to unlock the reference; and frankly it burdens the 'clients' with the plumbing of object management). Parts of your posts also suggest the use of the [Mediator pattern](http://bit.ly/Sn1DEM); which I am actually trying out now and it looks promising.
P.S. Thank you (and anyone else) for your effort to try and answer this.

Comment: I agree, I would prefer the version where the check-in/check-out happen automatically based upon "actions" being enqueued and completed.  But again, without any psuedo code or diagrams etc it is hard to make suggestions.  Knowing more how your client objects interact with the protocol objects would be helpful (unless it really is a single "enqueue" method exposed).